# Using Neo4j to store json data

Tags: json, neo4j

I have a network topology which consists of a number of switches and hosts.
Using Neo4j, I created a graph db that import the network topology information from a json file. and it works.
Now I need to store the switch statistics like the no. of packet sent, packet received, packet loss for a specific period of time. The json file consists of a huge no. of lines (more than 2000 line) for only one switch.
I face a problem storing this kind of data as node properties since it is huge data!
Any suggestions please. Does Neo4j can benefit me in storing this kind of data?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you share the structure of the JSON your working with

Comment: How can I upload the file? it's a json file with lots of lines (+2000) line @DanStarns

Comment: I am trying to use Arangodb instead. Since it is multi-model db. any suggestions?